# What are the advantages of using mutual information over Pearson correlation in network inference?

Tags: correlation, mutual-information

Does mutual information discriminate against fold change differences?

Answer (score 3):

See this question for the differences/advantages of using mutual information versus Pearson correlation or Spearman's rank:

- [What is the major difference between correlation and mutual information?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/what-is-the-major-difference-between-correlation-and-mutual-information)

> Does mutual information discriminate against fold change differences?

If that's the variation measure you use for your correlation values, then that is assumed for the hypothesized network.