# How to interpret the relationship between MI score and correlation score

Tags: correlation, mutual-information

I am confusing about the relationship between MI score and correlation score. I've searched for some information and know that:  `with Cov(,) we look at what non-independence does to their product, while in (,) we look at what non-independence does to their joint probability distribution.`
([Mutual information versus correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81659/mutual-information-versus-correlation))

But when I plot the graph of MI score and correlation score, I am still confused.
In the below graph, I am using the rolling window to continue plot the score between 'Topic' and 'Emotion'
As you can see in the x-axis where the range between 140-160, the correlation(Pearson) score is quite low, whereas the same period in the MI graph, the score is no significant low or high

[image]

Comment: Since MI and correlation are not measuring the same thing it would be surprising if they didn't behave differently.

Comment: So actually there is no relationship between MI score and correlation score? I thought there might have some contrast trend

Comment: It's not clear to me how you jumped from "not the same thing" to "no relationship". Correlation is a more specific kind of association.

Comment: oh! Because when I see the graph, there is no specific relationship between these two, that's why I am wondering if there is 'no relationship'.  So in the case that I show above, can I say there is no correlation between the 'topic' and 'emotion'? Because the Pearson score is usually lower than 0.3.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking. Lack of obvious relationship in a particular instance isn't necessarily any indication of lack of relationship in general.

Comment: sorry, I didn't ask very clear before. I mean in this case(the graph I show), can I say in **this period**, there is no relationship between the topic(Finance) and the emotion(Sadness)?

Comment: You need to do two things: 1. explain the axes of your plots (what's the x-axis?) and make sure your question reflects what you want to know. You'll need to edit your question.