# Does statistical association and dependence only include linear and nonlinear correlations

Tags: correlation, independence, association-measure

I know there are linear correlation measures such as Pearson that might not capture all cases of statistical dependence or nonlinear correlations. I know there are also nonlinear correlations, which can be measured by  distance correlation
or mutual information.

Then there's the idea of dependence and association
[" association is synonymous with dependence and is different from correlation (Fig. 1a). Association is a very general relationship: one variable provides information about another."](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.3587)

I know the [distance correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation)  and [mutual information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81659/mutual-information-versus-correlation) are other ways to measure dependence.
If we say 2 variables have a dependence/association, does that mean its either a  linear correlation or nonlinear correlation? Or is it possible for it to exist without these?

In the following [article](https://theincidentaleconomist.com/wordpress/causation-without-correlation-is-possible/?fbclid=IwAR0FxpJlx7Gho4Vh_d247rxEOD-BFvChq4xOFVH3i90a-mgv99APvzC4VJ8), they discuss a case where
" x and y are uncorrelated but their magnitudes are not. That is, there are functions of x and functions of y that are correlated."
This would this be a nonlinear correlation?